# allowing only confirmed users to login not working

Tags: php

I'm using the code below to make sure only confirmed users (confirmed is 1, else 0) can login, but this code displays the apologize message no matter what. How can I fix this? Thanks!

```
// make sure the user is confirmed
    $confirmstatus = query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", $_POST["username"]);
    if ($confirmstatus["confirmed"] == 0)
    {
        apologize("Please first confirm your account.");
    }
```

This is the query function

```
    /**
 * Executes SQL statement, possibly with parameters, returning
 * an array of all rows in result set or false on (non-fatal) error.
 */
function query(/* $sql [, ... ] */)
{
    // SQL statement
    $sql = func_get_arg(0);

    // parameters, if any
    $parameters = array_slice(func_get_args(), 1);

    // try to connect to database
    static $handle;
    if (!isset($handle))
    {
        try
        {
            // connect to database
            $handle = new PDO("mysql:dbname=" . DATABASE . ";host=" . SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

            // ensure that PDO::prepare returns false when passed invalid SQL
            $handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); 
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            // trigger (big, orange) error
            trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
            exit;
        }
    }

    // prepare SQL statement
    $statement = $handle->prepare($sql);
    if ($statement === false)
    {
        // trigger (big, orange) error
        trigger_error($handle->errorInfo()[2], E_USER_ERROR);
        exit;
    }

    // execute SQL statement
    $results = $statement->execute($parameters);

    // return result set's rows, if any
    if ($results !== false)
    {
        return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this is the apologize function

```
   /**
 * Apologizes to user with message.
 */
function apologize($message)
{
    render("apology.php", ["message" => $message]);
    exit;
}
```

And the render function.

```
    /**
 * Renders template, passing in values.
 */
function render($template, $values = [])
{
    // if template exists, render it
    if (file_exists("../templates/$template"))
    {
        // extract variables into local scope
        extract($values);

        // render header
        require("../templates/header.php");

        // render template
        require("../templates/$template");

        // render footer
        require("../templates/footer.php");
    }

    // else err
    else
    {
        trigger_error("Invalid template: $template", E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your function code alongside your first chunk.

Are you certain that your "query();" is acting in the proper method way?

Comment: This the query function.

Comment: You have given your query function, but another factor at play is your "apologize" function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Running:

```
$confirmstatus = query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", $_POST["username"]);
print_r($confirmstatus);
```

Double check that your function is infact returning an array.

Also try this as your query:

```
    $Checkusername = $_POST['username'];
   $confirmstatus = query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$Checkusername'");
```

Also. Your

```
function query(/* $sql [, ... ] */)
{ }
```

The Variables which are being passed through to the function have been commented out. If this is exactly like your code.. then I would recommend a revision to:

```
function query ($sql)
{ .... }
```

**EDIT**

```
 if ($confirmstatus["0"]['confirmed'] == 0)
    {
        apologize("Please first confirm your account.");
    }
```

I overlooked something. It seems you are being returned a multidimensional array
You need to look into the first array (in this case 0) and then look for your required field.

Comment: Just tried printing, and I got this: Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 20 [confirmed] => 1 [username] => test [hash] => $1$l4VE9aAZ$UPDMV68K9y2555Hr/FbJJ. [firstname] => [lastname] => ) )

Comment: Your query is running through correctly, try changing your check code to what i am about to update

Comment: New edit. This should work. When you try it out, report back with findings.

Comment: Ok, that was for the previous one.

Comment: Completely fine. Sorry about the confusion at the beginning. I forgot that fetchall(); from the PDO library returns a multidimensional array to which the coder will have to seek into array 1 then inside array 1 find said field. Don't forget to mark as answer with the green tick :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:
$confirmstatus returns an array which has the rest part

$confirmstatus = query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", $_POST["username"]);
    if ($confirmstatus[0]["confirmed"] == 0)
    {
        apologize("Please first confirm your account.");
    }

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).